# gitlab doesn't create project in gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

After I create project in gitlab, I still can't to push to it. I notice there is no project create in gitolite repositories folders where it should be there.

`cat /home/gitlab/gitlab/log/githost.log`  show below, the last time is just when I create the project in gitlab.

```
March 04, 2013 15:37 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
1c67fcf..25792ba  master -master

March 04, 2013 15:50 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
19952c7..f8ccebc  master -master

March 04, 2013 15:57 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
359de47..3683bc1  master -master

March 04, 2013 16:21 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
479836c..37a2aa9  master -master

March 04, 2013 16:23 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
37a2aa9..8771dee  master -master

March 04, 2013 16:32 -ERROR -Gitolite error -  remote: FATAL:
git config 'core.sharedRepository' not allowed remote: check
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file To git@42.62.26.7:gitolite-admin   
8771dee..f354a61  master -master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your gitolite configuration, as mentioned in [Issue 1769](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1769), for Gitolite V3:

> My `.gitolite.rc` looked like this

```
%RC = (
      # if you're using mirroring, you need a hostname.  This is *one* simple
      # word, not a full domain name.  See documentation if in doubt
      # HOSTNAME                  =>  'darkstar',
      UMASK                       =>  0007,
      '.*',
```

> changed it to

```
%RC = (
      # if you're using mirroring, you need a hostname.  This is *one* simple
      # word, not a full domain name.  See documentation if in doubt
      # HOSTNAME                  =>  'darkstar',
      UMASK                       =>  0007,
      GIT_CONFIG_KEYS     =>  '.*',
```

Note that the next GitLab release (5.0) won't use Gitolite anymore.